# Too many arguments fo function call

Tags: c++

I'm getting started with C++ and using a beginner project template for ATM Banking system. Alot of the functions are set up, but I am adding a function to check for duplicate account number when creating a new account. A user is asked to enter their new account number, which then I am adding a function to check if it exists now. If the account exists I want the function to run again and ask user for an account number again and run through the duplicate check again.

I get this message:

> error: too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 1
>       int dup = ac.check_duplicate(acno);

Here's what fires in order:
User chooses to create account:

```
void write_account()
{

    account ac;
    ofstream outFile;
    ifstream inFile;
    outFile.open("account.dat", ios::binary | ios::app);
    ac.create_account();
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&ac), sizeof(account));
    outFile.close();
}
```

Create_account:

```
void account::create_account()
{
    account ac;
    cout << "\nEnter The account No. :";
    cin >> acno;
    cout << "\nChecking account No...";

    int dup = ac.check_duplicate(acno);
    if (dup == 1)
    {
        cout << "\n\nEnter The Name of The account Holder : ";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.getline(name, 50);
        cout << "\nEnter Type of The account (C/S) : ";
        cin >> type;
        type = toupper(type);
        cout << "\nEnter The Initial amount(>=500 for Saving and >=1000 for current ) : ";
        cin >> deposit;
        cout << "\n\n\nAccount Created..";
    }
    cout << "\nAccount No. is taken. Please choose a different account No.";
    ac.create_account();
}
```

check_duplicate

```
    int check_duplicate(int n)
{
    bool found = false;
    int num;
    account ac;
    fstream File;
    File.open("account.dat", ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);
    if (!File)
    {
        cout << "File could not be open !! Press any Key...";
    }
    while (!File.eof() && found == false)
    {
        File.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&ac), sizeof(account));
        if (ac.retacno() == n)
        {
            return 0;
            found = true;
        }
    }
    File.close();
    if (found == false)
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: What is the **entire** error message? And which line causes the error?

Comment: ```ac.create_account();``` your ```create_account()``` function is recursive with no base case? Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<char *>(&ac)` has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @code-apprentince I've made the edit to the message above.

Comment: @george good catch, I've put an else if statement to check for dup == 0

Comment: `ac.check_duplicate(acno);` This calls member function `check_duplicate`, but `int check_duplicate(int n)` defines a free function by the same name, instead.

Comment: I may be using 'ac.' incorrectly. There is only one function check_duplicate. I thought I needed to call the function with ac. otherwise it was out of scope. Correct me with the proper way here?

Comment: @LuisRodriguez The error message `too many arguments to function call, expected 0` suggests that you have another `check_duplicate` declared elsewhere in the code *not* shown. This is precisely why you should post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @George: It’s rather more subtle than that: at the least we’d have to see the definition of `account` to know what validity it might have.

Comment: Is the check_duplicate declared inline or did you miss to specify the class scope? Should be: `int account::check_duplicate(int n){...}`